# Duplicating and adding sprites at runtime in Unity

Tags: unity, sprites

I am trying to create a 2D game in Unity in which objects keep falling from top and the player has to dodge them. Suppose I have created a sprite which serves as a single enemy that the player has to dodge.Now I have to create multiple such sprites at runtime so that they can keep on spawning from random positions.Despite searching on the net for quite some time i could not find a clear answer.

I am just a newbie and I am just starting to learn game development in Unity so answers in detail will be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it in Unity by creating prefabs in editor ([see video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQqVwsLxU90)) and then instanciating them in script ([read manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html)) or in editor.

Comment: Thank you very much I got what I was looking for. Could you explain how to destroy the prefabs once they are out of scene.

Comment: You are welcome. Prefabs are not destroyed, they are static to projects (i.e. shared between scenes). But objects instanciated from a prefab are destroyed as usual by calling Destroy(obj1).